# Bither max transaction fee is 1mBTC per kb. I don't want a stalled transaction

Tags: transaction-fees, bither

I've had my BTC with Bither for awhile.  Bither's max transaction fee is 1mBTC per kb.

If i am doing my math right

1mBTC per kb  = 100,000 Satoshis per kb.

(100,000 Satoshis / 1024) = (97.65625 Satoshis /byte)

According to https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/  this is 1/4 what it should be.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 12/12/2017, there is no updated version, either Android or Windows that allows Bither to go beyond the 1mBTC transaction fee.  At that transaction fee, it might take forever or never for a transaction to go through.

There is NO direct information on Bither on how to do this, but after nearly a full day of work, i figured out how to derive the Bitcoin private Key from the HDaccount wallet from Windows Bither. It took a bit of reading and trial and error but, i had success.

From Bither, I exported the Seed Phrase.  I then utilized the website at https://coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html.

Instead of trusting the website, even though it's supposedly java client based, i saved the website to an OFF INTERNET computer, and ran the webpage from my offline computer.  I put in the seed phrase which then spit out derived bitcoin addresses and private keys.

I was then able to use that private key to access my bitcoin from another software that has better up to date support including transaction fees.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by marking your answer as accepted so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution to the problem John!